# Install chrome driver on Amazon Linux 2 ARM

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium, amazon-linux-2

I am looking to install Chrome Driver (For my selenium project) on an Amazon Linux 2 (Arm 64).

I have done this on Ubuntu and seems pretty straight, it also seems straight on [AL2 x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72077341/how-do-you-install-chrome-on-amazon-linux-2), like this script from [Intoli](https://intoli.com/blog/installing-google-chrome-on-centos/) but it 404 when looking for Chrome on ARM :(. So far I see Chrome is not available for ARM so I see the alternative is to use Chromium.

I tried installing it manually but it seems there is no compiled on [Chromium downloads page](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads?authuser=0) for ARM.

Finally i found the [Electron's unofficial webdrivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732822/compile-chromedriver-on-arm), which seem to be the answer, and after downloading, installing dependencies (libXcursor, libXfixes, libXdamage) and running it:

```
[ec2-user@scraping1 current]$ chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.143 (6bf1afe83487405ea0aff37182f05e3db45559c2-refs/branch-heads/4951@{#831}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

And run my project I get:

```
2.7.3 :004 > Selenium::WebDriver::Service.driver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
 => "/usr/bin/chromedriver" 
 session = Capybara::Session.new
 Webdrivers::BrowserNotFound: Failed to find Chrome binary.
```

Which means i don't have Chrome installed, but then how to install it? I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626728/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-home-ec2-user-desktop-chromedriver-erro) which seems to be my same problem but it is unclear to me how to install Chromium; I see it is needed to download and use the chromedriver compiled for ARM64 which I have done already.

Comment: Never managed to accomplish this; i ended up switching to x64 architecture, but with new Amazon Linux 2023 it could be different