# Failed Puppeteer/Chromium installation with Node.js, ARM64 + AWS EC2, Linux 2

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppeteer, chromium, arm64, amazon-linux-2

I'm trying to install puppeteer on an AWS EC2 ARM64 instance with Amazon Linux 2 managed by Beanstalk, with Node.js v14. It's a `c7g.2xlarge` instance type.

**Installation Errors**

> The chromium binary is not available for arm64.
> If you are on Ubuntu, you can install with: sudo apt install chromium sudo apt install chromium-browser

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "install": "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=TRUE",
    "start": "node index.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^19.2.2",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^14.17.0"
  }
}
```

Two problems:

1. The installation tries to download Chromium even though `PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=TRUE` is set explicitly and fails with above mentioned error.
2. Trying to manually install Chromium fails as well.

All stackoverflow suggestions either focus on x86 instance types or Chrome driver installations on ARM, and the puppeteer GitHub issues only focus on Ubuntu OS or Apple Mac ARM devices. All of which doesn't solve the issue at hand.

**Applied settings**

- Set `.npmrc` with `unsafe-perm=true`
- `PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox` failed because of missing Firefox Nightly AMR64 version

**Things that didn't work**

❌ Installing Chromium via `sudo amazon-linux-extras install chromium` (or `google-chrome`, `chromium-browser`) after installing `sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y` fails because there is no such repo.

❌ `curl -k https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash` fails because it's not an x86 architecture.

❌ [Electron has an unofficial Chrome driver for ARM64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57586200/9986657), but I have no idea how to use this one. The driver was [successfully installed by this user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72188558/9986657), but there is no indication as to whether and how it worked with puppeteer.

❌ Changing the instance type to an AMD/Intel processor isn't feasible because the next related tiers `c6i.2xlarge` and `c6a.2xlarge` with Intel and AMD processors aren't supported in my region.

❌ [Compiling Chromium for ARM as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176794/how-do-i-cross-compile-chromium-for-arm) doesn't work because the EC2 instance is running on Amazon Linux 2 in a Beanstalk environment, and not on Ubuntu.

❌ Switching from Chromium to Firefox Nightly doesn't work. Even though the installation of Firefox works with `sudo amazon-linux-extras install firefox`, running `/usr/bin/firefox --headless` results in `X Server not found` errors.

❌ Installing a [pre-compiled snapshot form here](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) doesn't work because I can't a precompiled snapshot.

❌ [Custom install scripts for `.ebextensions`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5379#issuecomment-671891901) don't work because they're all targeted towards x86 archs.

❌ I also can't find a Chromium version here: https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/

## Update 1

The env variable `PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD` is ignored because it is upper cased. Moving `PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD` from `package.json` to the `.npmrc` file and lower casing it solves the installation error and puppeteer can at least be installed ([source](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2270#issuecomment-377682360)). In other words, ignore the suggestion of the puppeteer installer

> Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.

`.npmrc` file:

```
unsafe-perm=true
# PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true
# PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=true
puppeteer_skip_chromium_download=true
puppeteer_skip_download=true
```

However, installing Chromium manually still fails.

## Update 2

It's working with Firefox instead of Chromium. Here are the steps to get it working:

1. Create a folder `.ebextensions` in your project root dir, and create a new file `puppeteer.config` with:

```
commands:
  install_firefox:
    command: sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y && sudo amazon-linux-extras install firefox
```

This tells your EC2 installer to install Firefox once the code is deployed to the instance, before `npm install` runs.

2. Define the `executablePath` and `product` in puppeteer's config.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const options = {
  headless: true,
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // for Beanstalk env
  options.executablePath = '/usr/bin/firefox';
  options.product = 'firefox';
} else {
  // for my local Mac env
  options.executablePath = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome';
}

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);

// other puppeteer code
```

3. **Important**: don't use `await page.emulateMediaType('screen');`. It works with Chrome, but fails with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing Chromium with Firefox worked, but because `page.emulateMediaType('screen')` isn't available with Firefox, generated PDFs lacked the proper style and I ended up throwing the entire ARM64 Beanstalk environment out of the window.

### New Environment Setup

I set up a completely new Beanstalk environment with instances supporting the x86 architecture instead of ARM. A new environment was necessary because Beanstalk doesn't support x86 EC2 instances once the environment was build for ARM instances.

The processor type can be adjusted in the **Capacity/Auto Scaling** section during the custom configuration setup of the environment.

Ensure to select `x86` in the **Processor** section (see screenshot).

[image]

### Installing Chromium via `.ebextensions`

Once the environment was set up, I created a new folder `.ebextensions` inside my project root dir and added a new file `puppeteer.config` with:

[image]

```
commands:
  install_chrome:
    command: curl -k https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash
```

### Avoiding `npm install` hickups

Because the Beanstalk installer installs Chromium automatically before `npm install` is executed, we need to tell puppeteer to skip installing Chromium while `npm install` runs. We create the file `.npmrc` in the root dir and include:

```
unsafe-perm=true
puppeteer_skip_chromium_download=true
puppeteer_skip_download=true
```

### Setting Chromium `executablePath`

Chromium was installed to `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` on the EC2 instances, but this path doesn't match the path of my Chromium/Chrome version on my Mac. So, we need to update the `executablePath` accordingly.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const options = {
  headless: true,
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // for Beanstalk env
  options.executablePath = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable';
}

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);

// other puppeteer code
```